# Animated loading icon in ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menu-items

I'm developing an app with an account system linked to Firebase.

Well, the sign up process takes a few seconds and I wish to implement a rotating loading icon like this one in the action bar:

[image]

The only problem is that I don't know how to make the menu item rotate and how to disable it's onClick feature.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Runnable` to set the images from the drawables with `Thread.sleep(10);`.

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            stuff();
            finish();
        }
    }).start();
```

And

```
public void stuff(){
    for (int i=0;i<50;i+=5){ //put i< the number of images you have
        try {                //for your animation.
            Thread.sleep(10);
            //set your image here.
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more explicit, please?